# Check two arguments for null in an elegant way

Tags: java, collections, null, iterator, java-7

I am iterating over **two collection**s and check if both collections contain
the **same elements**. I can't use Java 8.

---

**edit 1 year after:**

I created the method in the question to check if two Collections contain the same elements, without thinking about the fact that I am passing two `Collection` implementations into the method.

But Collection does not determine how elements are sorted. And I am iterating over the collections. Thus, some implementation of Collection could save elements in random order, while containing the same elements.

---

Both collections contain **elements** that **are comparable** and the content
is defined as equal, if all elements return a `x.compareTo(y)` with 0.

**Two values are defined as different, if one of them is null, but not the other**.
I want to find an elegant way to compare on nullity and prevent 
a null check on the final `compareTo()`.

*My current implementation:*

```
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isSame(@Nullable Collection<T> a, @Nullable Collection<T> b) {

    if (a == null || b == null) {
        return (a == null && b == null);
    }

    if (a.size() != b.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    Iterator<T> aIt = a.iterator();
    Iterator<T> bIt = b.iterator();
    while (aIt.hasNext()) {
        T aValue = aIt.next();
        T bValue = bIt.next();
        if (aValue == null || bValue == null) {
            if (aValue == null ^ bValue == null) {
                return false;
            }
            //both null, don't compare, continue looping...
        } else if (aValue.compareTo(bValue) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to continue the while loop, if both values are null, because that is 
defined as equal.

But I am struggling with this part:

```
if (aValue == null || bValue == null) {
        if (aValue == null ^ bValue == null) {
            return false;
        }
}
```

*Question:*

**Is there a more elegant and readable way to compare on nullity, do a further compare if both are not null, return false if only one is null, and continue the loop, if both values are null?**

Comment: `if (aValue == null && bValue == null) continue;` does this not work ?

Comment: Sure, but then I have to check at least aValue for null before I can call compareTo, or it might crash with a NPE

Comment: Naive solution: create a new list for each collection, sort each list, then compare the sorted lists. More sensible approach: create a map of counts for each collection, with the keys being the elements and the values being the counts of each element in the collection (HashMap allows to have null as a key), then compare if both maps have the same entries, or just if their respective entry sets are equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence as follows should work well:

```
if(aValue == null && bValue == null) continue; // both null; continue
if(aValue == null || bValue == null) return false; // any null; return false
if(aValue.compareTo(bValue) != 0) { // both non-null; compare
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Damn you beat me to it by 7 seconds ;) I'll delete my answer!

Comment: @ParkerHalo And as I was typing the same to your post, you deleted ;)

Comment: Hmm I really like the approach, because it is shorter. Although it still contains (kind of same) three if conditions. But I won't get rid of them right?

Comment: @JacksOnF1re Well, the problem statement had three checks. Even if we reduce the number of if statements we would end up doing same number of comparisons anyhow.

Comment: @nullpointer Yes, I see..Let me think about this, some more couple of hours. But I doubt there is a better way. Thanks in advance - will mark the answer as correct, if there is no other way.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re Sure. More thoughts on the table and brainstorming is something I always cast my vote for.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re I'd like to add something if I may: In my opinion the readable option should (almost) always be preferred over the short option. It will help other people who have to read your code and even yourself when you return to 'old' code later.

Comment: @ParkerHalo I fully agree with you. That is why I've asked for a solution that is short and readable. Moreover this is also why I did not like my XOR approach in the first place. Thanks for mentioning!

Comment: Or a single `if(aValue==null? bValue!=null: (bValue==null || aValue.compareTo(bValue) != 0)) return false;` An alternative approach would be `if(aValue!=bValue && (aValue==null || bValue==null || aValue.compareTo(bValue) != 0)) return false;` this assumes that identical object references must be the same according to the comparator (anything else would be broken).

Answer (score 4):

In Java8, you can build a `Comparator` that would replace comparison sequence at cost of creating an extra object (you will need to decide if you care about that):

```
Comparator<T> cmp = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

The compararor will take care of null comparison for you (since you assume that two `null`s are equal):

```
while (aIt.hasNext()) {
    T aValue = aIt.next();
    T bValue = bIt.next();
    if (cmp.compare(aValue, bValue) != 0) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think thats the way to go. Also, you can store the comparator object into a static final field, so you don't need to recreate it every now and then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I can't use Java 8 here! I edited the question.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re, I don't think we should just discard my answer from this question: future reader may be able to use Java8, and might find my answer helpful. So I'll keep it here.

Comment: Sure sure! I think so, too.